# Is second-order ZFC categorical with regard to its proper class models

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, model-theory, mathematical-philosophy

Second-order ZFC offers partial categoricity in the sense that, given any two models, one of them must be isomorphic to an initial segment of the other [1].  However, this leaves questions regarding the height of the cumulative hierarchy unspecified.

So my question is if second-order ZFC can at least be said to be categorical with regard to its proper class models (i.e. having a unique proper class model up to isomorphism)? And in that sense is it also correct to say that ZFC2 has a unique 'largest' model (up to isomorphism), since the proper class models are 'larger' than the set models.

I am assuming standard semantics for second order logic (e.g. not Henkin semantics).

[1] http://web.mit.edu/arayo/www/puzzle.pdf

Comment: I don't think "proper class model with standard semantics" makes sense.  If we are using 1st order ZFC to talk about models of 2nd order ZFC, then there is no such thing as the collection of all classes.  Furthermore, 2nd order ZFC proves the consistency of 1st order ZFC in a straightforward way, so there is no hope of giving a natural proper-class interpretation of 2nd order ZFC.

Comment: The real challenge is to decide how you want to formalize the question. As Joel David Hamkins' answer explains, if we choose an arbitrary model of $V$ of ZFC as out metatheory to give a definition of full second-order semantics, then that model $V$ will think that $V$ is itself the only class model of full second-order ZFC. Does this really show what you wanted to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only second-order part that is needed for this is the second-order power set axiom.

That is, if $M$ is any proper class model of (a weak fragment of) first-order ZFC and satisfies the second-order power set axiom, then $M$ contains all sets. The reason is that if we iterate the power set operation inside $M$, then we will construct the actual $V_\alpha$'s, since $M$ is correct about power sets. And so every $V_\alpha$ is contained in $M$ and so $M=V$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you agree with Carl Mummert's interpretation of your answer (above)?: "As Joel David Hamkins' answer shows, if we choose an arbitrary model of V of ZFC as the definition of our second-order semantics, then that model V will think that V is the only model of second-order ZFC."

Comment: Yes, I think that Carl is exactly right.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  Doesn't the assumption that we are using 'standard semantics' for second order logic rule out at least some of these 'arbitrary' models of ZFC?

Comment: My view is that second-order logic is incoherent except when it takes place in some set-theoretic background. My argument here is that with respect to any such background, then any class model of ZFC+ the second-order power set axiom will be the entire universe.

Comment: In particular, for people who have some favored set theoretic background (such as a "platonisitic $V$" consisting of "all sets"), the argument goes through in their background like any other. So rather than being more restrictive, the viewpoint that second-order logic is only defined relative to a set-theoretic background is more general. The source of categoricity is not only the use of second-order semantics; it is also in the choice of a particular set-theoretic background in which to interpret those semantics. @Andy

Comment: This issue also underlies objections to the claim advanced by some that the CH and other set-theoretic questions are settled by second-order ZFC. If you in mind that there is one absolute background concept of set provided the semantics for the second-order logic, then this may be convincing; but others with a pluralistic viewpoint find this line way of argument to be circular.

Comment: JoelDavidHamkins and @CarlMummert I guess I'm not clear why you say that we need a full model of the set theoretic universe just to provide a coherent semantics for 2nd order logic?  In particular, the specification of the universe of sets involves transfinite iterations of powerset/union operations, whereas the semantics of 2nd order logic can be understood in terms of the application of a single iteration of powerset to a base set/model (and 3rd order logic requires just two such iterations, etc).

Comment: Also, in that sense it doesn't seem 'circular' to define something complex (e.g. the full universe of sets) in terms of something more basic (e.g. the single iteration of powerset implicit in quantification over 2nd order predicates).

Comment: Andy, my view is that second-order logic must take place with respect to some set-theoretic meta-theoretic background, since it makes use of the concept of subsets of the domain. Which sets are there? I find all talk of second-order logic to be essentially set-theoretic in nature. Whether a given second-order theory is categorical or satisfiable or whatever will depend on the set-theoretic ontological commitments of one's meta-theory. Thus, one might as well have asked a set theory question about the meta-theory instead.

Comment: Interesting. Though my sense is that the same argument could be made about 1st order logic, e.g. to understand the semantics of the universal quantifier you have to take as primitive the concept of 'all' elements in the *set* corresponding to the model.  Likewise, the standard semantics for 2nd order logic require us to take as primitive the concept of 'all subsets' of the model *set*. In both cases these are set theoretic primitives, but far short of the ontological commitments involved in a full theory of sets.

Comment: Also, it seems that a major advantage of 2nd order logic is that it allows for categorical versions of theories which are under-determined in 1st order logic (e.g. Piano arithmetic, etc), unless you're saying that the various 2nd order categoricity results are completely vacuous (or perhaps equivalent in some way to first-order results)?

Comment: Perhaps one can have a naive theory of "all subsets" without a larger background set theory, but set theory has shown that one's larger set theory can impact the nature of sets lower down. Consider how the existence of Woodin cardinals or other large cardinals affects descriptive set theory and even the collection of which kinds of reals exist. Thus, the fundamental nature of second-order arithmetic is affected by set theory high up. Second-order logic is really set theory.

Comment: To the extent that we allow non-standard semantics for power-set, wouldn't we expect that altering the interpretation for this concept would impact the truth of claims at both low and high levels of the cumulative hierarchy (in a correlated manner), leading to logical dependencies among facts about different levels.  But this seems consistent with the notion that when constrained to the standard semantics of the power-set (in 2nd order logic), the set of elements corresponding to 'all subsets' of a given model is fixed without any additional assumptions regarding the broader theory of sets.

Comment: The concept of "standard" power set semantics is dependent on one's set-theoretic background. Every set-theoretic background thinks its own power set concept is "standard", and they can disagree.

Comment: But it seems that the same could be said of the concept of "all elements in the model set" in the semantics of first order quantification, i.e. if we considered alternative semantics, then each interpretation would 'think' it was the correct one, but few would suggest that we have to put every potential semantics for 'all' on equal footing with the standard one (in analogy to the concept of 'all subsets of the model' in 2nd order logic).

Comment: I don't really see the same level of dependence in the two situations; I don't think they are analogous. It seems to me that any two set-theoretic backgrounds will agree on the scope of a universal or existential quantifier over a domain they have in common, namely, the they each range over the elements of that domain. This is not to say that they need to agree on their full theories of truth in a structure, in light of the results discussed in: http://jdh.hamkins.org/satisfaction-is-not-absolute/, which I think are very much connected to these issues.

Comment: Two set-theoretic backgrounds will only agree on first order quantification because we are choosing (quite reasonably) to hold the semantics of that logical concept fixed.  But surely we could, if we wanted, consider alternative semantics in which 1st order quantification 'ignored' certain types of elements (in analogy to alternative semantics of 2nd order quantification). btw, thanks for the link, I'll take a look!

Comment: I agree with you that there are all kinds of possible strange semantics, and it is part of my point that one generally needs to specify what semantics is intended. This is precisely why I believe that "second-order logic" is not so meaningful apart from a set-theoretic context providing the meaning of the second-order quantifiers.

Comment: Given that we agree that both 1st and 2nd order quantification are open to alternative semantics (in addition to the intuitive/standard semantics), I'm unclear as to why you see such a stark contrast between the two logics; i.e. you view 2nd order logic as having no meaningful notion of standard semantics outside the context of the chosen background theory, whereas you seem to accept 1st order logic as having a standard semantics with special status (e.g. when say that "any two set-theoretic backgrounds will agree on the scope of a universal or existential quantifier...").

Comment: Nobody holds the alternative first-order semantics you mentioned. But many mathematicians work in different set-theoretic theories, with CH and without, with Diamond or PFA or large cardinals, etc. There is no "standard" second-order logic divorced from a meta-theory settling those kinds of questions. The existence of a huge variety of set-theoretic possibility is the central discovery of set theory in the past fifty years.

Comment: It may be true that no one holds these alternative 1st order semantics, but is that contingent fact (or questions about what 'many mathematicians' do or don't work on) really the reason that standard 1st order semantics has special status in your view. Isn't the issue just that it's self-evident that the semantics of the universal quantifier corresponds to the concept of 'all elements in the model' (i.e. not excluding any elements), and other potential semantics are merely toy theories that don't reflect the intended concept.

Comment: Also, regarding the 'central discovery' of alternate set-theoretic theories with opposing claims about the nature of sets, isn't it inevitable given Godel's incompleteness theorem that there are facts that are independent of any particular 1st order axiomatization; so from that perspective, I don't see why specific examples of facts (e.g. CH) which happen to be independent of ZFC1 would count as evidence against a standard semantics of 2nd order logic (any more than non-standard models of 1st order arithmetic would count as evidence against the standard concept of the natural numbers).

Comment: I've written on exactly that debate; you can see my paper here: http://jdh.hamkins.org/themultiverse/.

Comment: @Joel I am sorry if my question is impolite, but I wonder what is the second-order power set axiom. I can imagine second-order replacement and comprehension easily, but I can't imagine the statement of the second-order power set axiom.

Comment: The axiom says every set $x$ has a power set $y$ that contains ALL the subsets of $x$, using the second order quantifier to get all the subsets. Namely, $\forall x\exists y\forall Z (Z\subset x\iff Z\in y)$, where lower case means first-order and upper case means second order. The final expression $Z\in y$ is shorthand for $\exists z\ z\in y\wedge\forall w (w\in Z\iff w\in z)$, which is to say that the second-order object $Z$ is extensionally identical with $z$.